# Checking if a static function exists at compile time

Tags: c++, compile-time, weak-linking

function.**c** (I can't edit this file)

```
#define FOO    1

#if FOO == 1
    void Foo() {}
#endif
```

**cpp**

```
class MyClass
{
#if FOO == 1
    void CppFoo()
    {
        Foo();
    }
#endif
}
```

I want to do the same thing, but without using the define `TEST` in the main.cpp file

What I want to do:

```
class MyClass
{
#if (extern "c" Foo() exist)
    void CppFoo()
    {
        Foo();
    }
#endif
}
```

The `CppFoo()` method will not have to be declared if the static function `Foo()` has not been declared.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please pick one programming language.

Comment: Do you mean "compile time" or "link time"? By "exist", do you mean "defined" or "declared"? Compile time can detect declared but it has no insight into whether it is defined, because whether a function is defined is determined by what you pass to the linker.

Comment: You don't have a static function, you have a global function with external linkage. Since C++ operates on translation unit level, there is no way to determine anything outside a given translation unit. What you want is impossible.

Comment: Note the C++ code won't work even if the function is defined unless there's a declaration `extern "C" void Foo();`. Remember that in C, `void Foo();` and `void Foo(void);` are not the same!

Comment: @RaymondChen I meant "declared", I edited my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Does the `function.c` file have an associated header file such as `function.h` that you can `#include`?

Comment: It seems unwise to have this code's functionality depend on whether or not you remembered to `#include` the header that declares `Foo()`. That's the sort of thing you want the compiler to remind you about, not gloss over. What is the real problem here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a weak attribute, for example:

file a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo() __attribute__ ((weak));
int foo() {}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo();
}
```

File b.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo () {
    printf("Hello Wurld!\n");
}
```

Now if you do not compile and link b.c, then the default (no-op) function `foo()` is called, otherwise the function `foo()` from b.c.

Comment: Sorry, I modified my initial question to suit my specific case.

Comment: @Parmi93 Above solution still works, assuming that "exist" means "defined".